# Terminal decrease privileges

Tags: linux, perl, privileges, debian-based

Currently I'm working on a perl script (for Debian based OS'es) that automatically installs some software packages. Therefore the script needs root privileges. As you all know this can be done by adding `sudo` before the command.

For some configurations however, the terminal user may not be the root. So my question is, how can I decrease the privileges and return to the user that opened the terminal.

I already tried the following code, but it closes the terminal and thats not what I want.

> $result = `exit`;

Comment: `sudo -u nonroot whoami`

Answer (score 0):

When you're root, you can use `sudo -u user cmd...` to run a command as `user`. Since you're already root, it won't ask for a password.